# Roads with trees: any disadvantages?

Tags: cities-skylines

What are the functional differences between roads with trees or grass and plain roads?

I know that roads with trees reduce noise pollution.  They also seem to make people living nearby happy—not sure if this is purely from the reduced noise or something else.  Do they have any disadvantages?  Are there any other functional differences between the road types?

Plain roads seem to have parking spaces. Are these purely cosmetic or do they affect how the game works?

Comment: I don't have a full answer so I'll just leave a comment, from memory roads with trees reduce noise pollution, and so increase the happiness / value of any residents living near them.

Answer (score 5):

Parking space is not only a cosmetic.
Due to every CIM being simulated in one way or in another, when they go somewhere they take their car if its not close enough to their home.
They drive to nearest park space to the destination OR nearest Transportation option and then walk the remaining distance.
So having enough parking space is a great way to free up a lot of traffic,and having parking spaces on both side of the roads prevents the CIM from driving around and looking for a park space and adding to the traffic.

So in my opinion having the right balance between tree lined and normal roads is ideal.
[Source](https://steamcommunity.com/app/255710/discussions/0/611704531886007762/)

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't answer my question.  I explicitly asked if those parking spaces make a difference in how the game works or whether they are purely cosmetic.  The cost is not a functional difference.